# streamlit latex

Tags: python, web, latex, streamlit

Can anyone help me with the layout of a streamlit website? I create a website with streamit, however, I use st.latex and the layout of my website looks like this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyyTn.png)

I want the lines to be aligned to the left.

##### Sample Code

```
import streamlit as st

st.set_page_config(layout="wide")

st.latex(r'''
    \text{This is a gradient algorithm where step size } \alpha_{k}\text{ is chosen to minimize }\phi_{k}(\alpha)=f\left(\mathbf{x}^{k}-\alpha \nabla f\left(\mathbf{x}^{k}\right)\right).
''')

st.latex(r'''
    \bullet\textbf{ Step 1:}\text{ Let }\mathbf{x}^{0}\text{ be a starting point.}
''')

st.latex(r'''
    \bullet\textbf{ Step 2:}\text{Assign k := 0}
''')

st.latex(r'''
    \bullet\textbf{ Step 3:}\text{ Find }\nabla f\left(\mathbf{x}^{k}\right).\text{ If }\nabla f\left(\mathbf{x}^{k}\right)=0,\text{ then go to }7^{\text {th }}\text{ Step, otherwise go to next step.}
''')
```

##### Sample output

[image]

Comment: What is wrong with your current layout?

Comment: I want the lines to be aligned to the left

Comment: I use st.latex and they are all centered, I want them to align to the left. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Can you post a sample code?

Comment: st.latex(r'''\text{This is a gradient algorithm where step size } \alpha_{k}\text{ is chosen to minimize }\phi_{k}(\alpha)=f\left(\mathbf{x}^{k}-\alpha \nabla f\left(\mathbf{x}^{k}\right)\right).''')
    st.latex(r'''\bullet\textbf{ Step 1:}\text{ Let }\mathbf{x}^{0}\text{ be a starting point.}''')
    st.latex(r'''\bullet\textbf{ Step 2:}\text{Assign k := 0}''')
    st.latex(r'''\bullet\textbf{ Step 3:}\text{ Find }\nabla f\left(\mathbf{x}^{k}\right).\text{ If }\nabla f\left(\mathbf{x}^{k}\right)=0,\text{ then go to }7^{\text {th }}\text{ Step, otherwise go to next step.}''')

Comment: Did you check the [docs on latex](https://katex.org/docs/supported.html) used by streamlit?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a hack on css on class `katex-html`. Add the `text-align: left;`

Add it after `st.set_page_config(layout="wide")` from sample code above.

```
st.markdown('''
<style>
.katex-html {
    text-align: left;
}
</style>''',
unsafe_allow_html=True
)
```

##### Output

[image]